# Puppet not recognising my module

Tags: freebsd, puppet

I am trying to create a custom provider for package but for some reasons I keep on getting

> err: Could not run Puppet configuration client: Parameter provider
>   failed: Invalid package provider 'piprs' at
>   /usr/local/src/ops/services/puppet/modules/test/manifests/init.pp:5

I have added pluginsync=true in puppet.conf in both client and server. I have created the following rb file in module/test/lib/puppet/provider/package/piprs.rb. I am basically trying to create a custom provider for package resource type

```
#require 'puppet/provider/package' 

Puppet::Type.type(:package).provide(:piprs,
      :parent => ::Puppet::Provider::Package) do

      commands : pip => "/usr/local/bin/pip"

      desc "Python packages via `pip`."

      def create
            pip "freeze"
      end

      def destroy
      end

      def exists?
      end

    end
```

In the puppet.conf, there is the following source attribute

```
      pluginsource = puppet://puppet/plugins
```

I am not sure what it is. If you need anymore details, please do post a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first - you do realize there is already a Python pip provider in core?

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/package/pip.rb

If that isn't what you want - then lets move on ...

For starters - try your module without a Puppet master - this is going to be better for development anyway. You need to make sure Ruby can find the library path:

```
export RUBYLIB=<path_to_module>/lib
```

Then, try writing a small test in a .pp file:

```
package { "mypackage": provider => "piprs" }
```

And run it locally:

```
puppet apply mytest.pp
```

This will rule out a code bug in your provider versus a plugin sync issue.

I notice there is a space between the colon and the command - that isn't your problem is it?

```
commands : pip => "/usr/local/bin/pip"
```

If you can get this working without a puppetmaster, your problem is sync related.

There are a couple of things that can go wrong - make sure the file is sync'd properly on the client:

```
ls /var/lib/puppet/lib/puppet/provider/package
```

You should see the piprs.rb file there. If it is, you may need to make sure your libdir is set correctly:

```
puppet --configprint libdir
```

This should point to /var/lib/puppet/lib in most cases.

Comment: Thank you.. I ll test it out and update you.. But it's very descriptive .. I am hopeful that it ll help me get through the problem!!! And I do realize that there is already a pop provider I am trying to write a new one though to learn